# r + shiny + ggplot2 + flexdashboard object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, flexdashboard

I am currently making a dashboard to produce a dynamic plot depending on user input. I collect 3 parameters from the user: the starting date, ending date to set the time window in my plot and the specific physical site he wants to see information about.
The dataset I am using is a simple csv file with dates and numeric physical data.

I'm getting the following error related to my ds() function called in the renderPlot:

`object of type 'closure' is not subsettable` 
I thought the parenthesis would solve this but they did not, I think my ds() function does return a dataframe which should be the correct data type for the data argument in the ggplot function call but it is not. Maybe there is a problem when I wrap the ggplot call in the renderPlot function but I was not able to debug this.
I'm a bit confused
If somebody can help me I'd appreciate that.
Thanks

Here is the code

````
# préparation des tables (préliminaire)
dataset_stockage <- read.csv2('stock-quotidien-stockages-gaz.csv')
dataset_stockage[,2] <- as.numeric(dataset_stockage[,2])
dataset_stockage$date <- as.Date(dataset_stockage$date,format="%d/%m/%Y")
dataset_stockage <- arrange(dataset_stockage,date)

dataset_debit <- read.csv2('debit-quotidien-stockages-gaz.csv')
dataset_debit[,2] <- as.numeric(dataset_debit[,2])

dataset_impexp <- read.csv2('imports-exports-commerciaux.csv')
dataset_impexp <- dataset_impexp %>% mutate(date = str_replace_all(date, "-", "/"))
dataset_impexp$date <- as.Date(dataset_impexp$date,format="%Y/%m/%d")
dataset_impexp <- arrange(dataset_impexp,date)
```

# Stockage de gaz naturel 

Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Selectionnez le PITS que vous souhaitez visualiser ainsi que la plage temporelle qui vous intéresse

```{r}
dataset_stockage$date <- format(dataset_stockage$date, "%Y-%m-%d")

selectInput("pit", label = "PITS à visualiser:",
            choices = c(unique(dataset_stockage$pits)))

dateInput(
  "startdate",
  "Date de début: ",
  value = min(dataset_stockage$date, na.rm = TRUE),
  min = min(dataset_stockage$date, na.rm = TRUE),
  max = max(dataset_stockage$date, na.rm = TRUE),
  language = "fr"
)

dateInput(
  "enddate",
  "Date de fin: ",
  value = max(dataset_stockage$date, na.rm = TRUE),
  min = min(dataset_stockage$date, na.rm = TRUE),
  max = max(dataset_stockage$date, na.rm = TRUE),
  language = "fr"
)
```

Column
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Plot du niveau de stockage dans le site demandé

```{r}
ds <- reactive({dataset_stockage[dataset_stockage$pits==input$pit,] %>% ds[ds$stock_fin_de_journee<6*1000000000,] %>%
subset(ds,(date<as.Date(input$enddate)&date>as.Date(input$tartdate)))
})

renderPlot({ggplot(data=ds(),aes(x=date)) + geom_point(mapping=aes(y=stock_fin_de_journee)) + 
          labs(title = "Niveau de stockage (GWh PCS 0C)",
               x = "Date",
               y = "Stock de gaz (GWh PCS 0C)")
})

```
````

Comment: From a glance at your code `subset(ds,(date<as.Date(input$enddate)&date>as.Date(input$tartdate))` looks suspicious. As `ds` is the name of the `reactive` and as your pipe a dataset into `subset` it should most probably be `... %>% subset(date<as.Date(input$enddate) & date>as.Date(input$tartdate))`. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a minimal working flex dashboard and snippet of your data or some fake data if required to render your dashboard.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot, you helped me solve this, this was indeed the issue, now I fixed it to:
```r
ds <- reactive({dataset_stockage[dataset_stockage$pits==input$pit,] %>% filter(stock_fin_de_journee<6*1000000000) %>%
subset((date<as.Date(input$enddate)&date>as.Date(input$tartdate)))
})

renderPlot({ggplot(data=ds(),aes(x=date)) + geom_point(mapping=aes(y=stock_fin_de_journee)) + 
          labs(title = "Niveau de stockage (GWh PCS 0C)",
               x = "Date",
               y = "Stock de gaz (GWh PCS 0C)")
})
```

Comment: However, no error left but I cannot see the graph in my dashboard, I just get a blank figure now. It looks like the fetch in the dataset is empty, no rows are selected, however when I test the pipe locally it correctly fetches the data. Seems strange

Comment: Check your `date` column, at a second glance I would guess it should be `dataset_stockage$date <- as.Date(dataset_stockage$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")`. Or if it is already a proper date, then drop the line as `format()` will convert a date to a a character and hence your date filter will not work.

Comment: You are right, it's the date filter that does not work and returns an empty dataset, I tried removing the date conditions in the ds() and it works well. However, I do not really understand your message ? My dateInput is returning something like that: "2010-11-01" and I'm putting this in the Date format using as.Date() and comparing it to another date ? How come it does not work ?

Comment: My guess was that using `dataset_stockage$date <- format(dataset_stockage$date, "%Y-%m-%d")` caused the issue as it will convert `dataset_stockage$date` to a `character`. But actually it should not. Could you provide a small snippet of your data as `dput()`, i.e. read your dataset via `dataset_stockage <- read.csv2(...)`. Afterwards run `dput(head(dataset_stockage))` and copy & paste the output into your code. Doing so I can have a look at your data and run your code.

Comment: Solved! there was just a mis spelling